# libvlc: Caching file and seek issues

Tags: c++, video-streaming, vlc, libvlc

I have a player that uses `libvlc` to play youtube files and it plays fine.
Problem is it does not cache the file and when I pull slider to the previous position (let say to  position 0 sec) it starts to download afresh instead of reusing what was previous downloaded. VLC works fine in this respect so I believe I'm missing something here.

Any pointer, link, suggestion or solution is welcome!

Comment: thanks ravenspoint for adding tag for me!

Comment: What about trying with properly configured local Squid instance? Squid can cache partial downloads, IIRC.

Comment: Watch your "i"s and your "l"s -- [tag:libvlc] exists, while "libvic" is a thing that should not be.

Comment: I'd re-ask your question on the VLC forum...

Comment: @rodgerpack, my IP is blocked as spam in vlc forum. Not only I cannot post there (or even login), I cannot search anything. So if you have account there you can do me a favor to post and put a link there

Comment: @Charles thanks for correction. I did not notice the typo!

Comment: @wilx, what is local Squid Instance?

Comment: @Stefano http://www.squid-cache.org/

Comment: I see thanks. I'm trying to connect on how to use it with vlc/C++